# crypt with AES 256 2 files inside txt

Tags: python, encryption, pycryptodome

i have a problem, i got 2 txt files inside other txt, the txt is called secrets.txt ,

the code is the next...

```
import os
import random
import hashlib
import socket
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

key = b'0123456789abcdef'

pathfiles = open('secrets.txt', 'r')
pathfiles = pathfiles.readlines()

print(pathfiles)
for archvi in pathfiles:
    archvi = archvi.rstrip()
    IV = 16 * b'\x00'
    mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    cipher = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)
    openfile = open(archvi, 'rb')
    readfile = openfile.readlines()
    readfile = readfile
    openfile.close()
    encoding = cipher.encrypt(readfile)
    os.system("rm ")+ archvi
    openfile2 = open(archvi, 'wb')
    openfile2.write(encoding)
    openfile2.close()
```

inside the file secrets.txt are the next content....

```
/home/kali/Desktop/SecretMessage.txt
/home/kali/Desktop/hello.png
```

output when i execute my python file is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/holis.py", line 31, in <module>
    encoding = cipher.encrypt(readfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 178, in encrypt
    c_uint8_ptr(plaintext),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py", line 143, in c_uint8_ptr
    raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))
TypeError: Object type <class 'list'> cannot be passed to C code
```

how i can fix it?

Comment: If you want to encrypt the entire file, then don't use `readlines`.  Use `readfile = open(archvi,'rb').read()` to read the entire file at once.

Comment: And your `rm` call is wrong as well.  You don't need to use `os.system`, you can use `os.remove(arcvhi)` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your call to `os.system` was wrong, you don't need to remove the file if you are immediately going to open it for writing.  That will replace the older file.

```
import os
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'0123456789abcdef'

pathfiles = open('secrets.txt', 'r').readlines()
print(pathfiles)
for archvi in pathfiles:
    archvi = archvi.rstrip()
    IV = b'\x00' * 16
    mode = AES.MODE_CBC
    cipher = AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)
    readfile = open(archvi, 'rb').read()
    encoding = cipher.encrypt(readfile)
    open(archvi, 'wb').write(encoding)
```